# react-query: how to refetch query, when query isStale

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

Good morning,
I have several views in my application that depend on each other.

In view X, I display all user activities. Here is the code that retrieves this data.

```js
export type UseIntegrationsProps = GetIntegrationRequest & {
  enabled: boolean;
};

export const useIntegrations = ({
  order,
  filters,
  enabled,
}: UseIntegrationsProps) => {
  return useQuery<Integration[]>({
    queryFn: () => getIntegrations({ order, filters }),
    queryKey: commonQueriesFactory.integrations.item(filters, order),
  });
};
```

In view Y, the user has the option to add a new activity.

```js
type UsePostActivityProps = {
  id: string | undefined;
};

export const usePostActivity = ({
  substreamId,
}: UsePostActivityProps) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const { onErrorToast } = useToastNotification();

  const { mutateAsync: addActivityMutation, isLoading } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: addActivity,
  });


  const onActivityPost = async (text: string) => {
    try {
      await addActivityMutation({ id, text });
      // invalidating here 
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(substreamQueriesFactory.activities.all(id));
    } catch (e) {
      onErrorToast('Oops! Something went wrong, failed to post activity. Try again.');
    }
  };

  return { onActivityPost, isLoading };
};
```

Unfortunately, when I switch from view Y to view X, the query does not download, even though it returns `isStale` set to true.

In addition, when I use `refetchType: 'all'`, the query gets the new data, but immediately, and I don't want the data to be fetched, even though the user has not yet switched to the X view. **I am aware that this query is not active and therefore does not fetch unless I use `refetchType: 'all'`.**

So therefore my question is as follows:
**Is there any option to fetch the query when it is invalid ( `isStale: true` )?**

For example:

1. User goes to X view and gets his latests activities ( query is not stale ).
2. User goes to Y view and adds a new activity. Moreover, query from view X is being invalidated, so it's stale now.
3. User goes to X view, query is invalid as it's stale, but it's not being fetched :(

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, when I switch from view Y to view X, the query does not download, even though it returns isStale set to true.

This should work, unless you have turned off `refetchOnMount`. By using `queryClient.invalidateQueries`, you will:

- immediately refetch all matching, active queries
- mark all matching, inactive queries as stale so that they will be refetched when they are used the next time

So when you switch back from view Y to view X, the query should be picked up as stale, and with the default of `refetchOnMount: true`, stale queries should be refetched when a new query mounts.